# v'31/01/2017 22:38:22 to to_date(dated,'dd/mm/yyyy)'' ORA-01843: not a valid month 01843. 00000 - "not a valid month" how to deal with it?

Tags: oracle, date

in my table i have varchar column, in that i have stored date as  `31/01/2017 22:38:22` and i tried to convert it to oracle date as follows ,with two different queries as folllows:

```
 1> SELECT TO_DATE(date_d,'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM emapleTable;
 2> SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_d,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM emapleTable;
```

for the two queries  the following error is coming `ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"`
how to get date in this format `31/01/2017`? please can anyone help me, thank you.

Comment: Do you want a date or a timestamp?

Comment: I hope you are going to change the table design so as to store the datetime in an appropriate data type (timestamp or date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TO_DATE function with correct format string`. Try below query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(date_d, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as date_d FROM emapleTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you easily get `'31/01/2017'` of course by applying a substring function:

```
 substr(date_d, 1, 10)
```

If you want to have this converted to date, use the appropriate format (31 cannot be MM which is the month, but must be DD for the day of course):

```
 to_date(substr(date_d, 1, 10), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```